# rails devise - redirect doesn't call javascript code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mixpanel

I'm adding a mixpanel track event on User signup.

It works by adding the data to session[:event_tracking_queue].
Then when a html page is rendered it is appended to the response body.

Problem with Devise is it renders as expected

```
"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"******">redirected</a>.<script>\n//<![CDATA[\nmixpanel.track(\"Signed Up\");\n//]]>\n</script></body></html>"
```

Problem is the event is never triggered.

My thinking is it redirects before the event can be triggered.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are loading the mixpanel library on this page, too, right? I ask because you show an entire document (not some partial or template).

Comment: Absolutely, the issue I believe is the redirect, it works on all other pages.

Comment: I've sold it, I put a conditional on the code that appends the session data. If self.status == 302, skips and leaves session data in queue.